# Serialize LocalDateTime with only milliseconds with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, java-time, jsr310

I want to serialize a `LocalDateTime` to textual format while only showing milliseconds. I tried the following example:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS);

final LocalDateTime t = LocalDateTime.of(2014, 3, 30, 12, 30, 23, 123456789);

System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(t));
```

This outputs:

```
"2014-03-30T12:30:23.123456789"
```

So the precision is still in nanoseconds, despite to not show them as per `mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS)`.

I expected:

```
"2014-03-30T12:30:23.123"
```

Why is this? How can I fix this?

Comment: I am using currently using version 2.9.8 of Jackson.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you disabled WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, enabling or disabling WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS does nothing because localDateTime isn't in the timestamp representation anymore.

If you enable WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS and then disable WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, you'll get the desired result but in another form ([2014,3,30,12,30,23,123]), so it's also not an option.

So there are basically only two options to achieve the expected result:

1. The easiest - use this:
   `System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(t.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS)));`

   (Remember that you can safely remove `mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS);`, as it does nothing in this case).
2. A more complicated way (without truncating the time):

   ```
   DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
   SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
   simpleModule.addSerializer(new LocalDateTimeSerializer(dateTimeFormatter));

   final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);

   final LocalDateTime t = LocalDateTime.of(2014, 3, 30, 12, 30, 23, 123456789);

   System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(t));
   ```

   (In that case you don't even need to use JavaTimeModule).